# How to root Samsung Galaxy A5?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have Samsung Galaxy A5, SM-A500H running Android 5.0.2, downloaded from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/51317/A500HXXU1BOG4_A500HODD1BOG4_BNG/). I want to root it.

The only root available right now AFAIK, is CF-Auto-Root, as described [here](http://androidxda.com/root-samsung-galaxy-a5-sm-a500h) for example. But this root breaks everything. All the apps stop running when you reboot the phone and you have reinstalled the firmware, it doesn't work.

Is there another way to root my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently used Kingroot, installed without computer assistance (downloaded the .apk with the device browser via wifi and installed from the device's internal storage), to root a device so obscure I haven't seen a single reference to any fixes, custom ROM, or even version upgrades: the Visual Land Prestige Elite 10Q tablet.  Kingroot took about ten minutes to run, including rebooting the device, and the only thing I don't like is that I have to hold the tablet in portrait orientation whenever I use any Kingroot function, because it doesn't recognize screen rotation.

Obviously, I haven't tried this software with a Galaxy A5, but it should be fine.

Comment: i tried using kingroot the very next day after asking my question, didn't work, cause back then it didn't support my device, since you haven't tried it with an A5, I assume that kingroot still dont support my device, since A5 isn't a mainstream device

Comment: Kingroot was updated just days ago, and appears to update frequently.  My Elite 10Q is certainly not a mainstream device; even the manufacturer hasn't provide a Lollipop update, never mind Marshmallow.  I'd recommend trying again; all you've lost if it doesn't work is a few minute downloading, installing the .apk, and running it.

Comment: ok will try it again and let you know, fingers crossed

Comment: i used the apk as suggested, worked, restarted my phone, nothing breaks, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be: no, this is currently the only *practical* way to go. 
It fully supports the current Android firmware and future firmwares as well since it is not firmware dependent.

What exactly do you mean by the apps *stop running*? Apps stop running every time you restart your phone. So maybe you meant that they stop *working*? 
CF-Auto-Root is the safest and easiest method and **no data should be lost**. You should **not have to reinstall firmware.** If you used the method correctly, your apps should be working as before.

Please note that the tutorial that you have linked is only for **Android 4.4.4 with a specific built ID**. Since your device is not running on the same Android Version and built ID, then you need to download and flash the firmware to match the one from the tutorial *before* rooting it. Or check other tutorials to use this method with your specific Android version and build ID.

Comment: "*The short answer would be: no, this is currently the only practical way to go*" -- how did you conclude this fact?

Comment: Because, this is a software that does complex work for you and I am certain that it is the only one currently available that does this for this device model. Of course you could do it yourself if you know how to hack into your phone but those who can do that don't ask for rooting software.

Comment: why should i even care about the build ID and you said above that the root is not firmware dependent? I flashed and rooted many devices, never had to care. All the apps will of course still be there after rooting but it says that app x has stopped running, you press okay and it says app y stopped running, all the apps stop running.  My firmware is running fine, it's just that when I root, and reboot, all the apps stop running, I tried it 4 times yesterday, flash and root flash and root and flash again, it doesn't take a genius to root. Did you root your android lolipop using the Cf-auto-root?

Comment: I assume that built ID does matter in this case since it specifically states that warning on the site you linked. But I can not look into every tutorial for every device. That CF-Auto-Root is not firmware dependent only means that you will be able to use it with every firmware if using the right method, following the correct steps. There are different methods depending on which firmware you want to flash. I do know that CF-Auto-Root generally does work with Lollipop and yes, I did root Android Lollipop using CF-Auto-Root but on a Nexus 5 and 7.

Comment: all tutorials are the same download cf-root open odin and press start, i don't see any difference between the articles whatsoever